# 'Missing or duplicate parameters' in Access Token Response

Tags: node.js, lambda, axios

I'm trying to fetch the OAuth access token with the lambda function but getting fhe following error:

```
data: {
      error: 'invalid_request',
      error_description: 'Missing or duplicate parameters'
    }
```

This is the code:

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

exports.handler = async (event) => {

   var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://******/auth/oauth/v2/token',
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: '*********',
        client_secret: '******'
      
      }
    };
    
    try {
      const resp = await axios.request(options);
      console.log(resp.data)
    } catch (err){
      console.error(err);
    }
};
```

When I try to run the request with the Postman it returns the valid token.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) you have to correctly serialize the `data` before sending the request when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @derpirscher, I had to properly serialize the data object using `'qs'` library. After that I was able to fetch the access token successfully.

```
var axios = require("axios").default;
const qs = require('qs');

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  var data = {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: '*********',
        client_secret: '************'
  };


   var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://************/auth/oauth/v2/token',
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: qs.stringify(data)
    };
    
    try {
      const resp = await axios.request(options);
      console.log(resp.data)
    } catch (err){
      console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: `const qs = require('querystring');` also works and doesn't require an additional dependency.